# Unable to install python3-tk on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS:

```
user@vmubu01:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

And I am unable to install python3-tk using 'apt-get install' command as you can see below:

```
user@vmubu01:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-tk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  tix python3-tk-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-tk
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 91 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/101 kB of archives.
After this operation, 891 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 206924 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-tk_3.6.8-1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-tk:amd64 (3.6.8-1~18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-tk_3.6.8-1~18.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py', which is also in package libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 3.6.8-1+xenial1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-tk_3.6.8-1~18.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am also unable to install it using pip, see the error below:

```
user@vmubu01:~$ pip3.6 install python3-tk
Collecting python3-tk
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-tk (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3-tk
```

If I try to run the 'apt --fix-broken install' command I get:

```
user@vmubu01:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-tk
Suggested packages:
  tix python3-tk-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-tk
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 91 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/101 kB of archives.
After this operation, 891 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 206924 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-tk_3.6.8-1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-tk:amd64 (3.6.8-1~18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-tk_3.6.8-1~18.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py', which is also in package libpython3.6-stdlib:amd64 3.6.8-1+xenial1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-tk_3.6.8-1~18.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I please advise

Comment: Do my a favor and check if `/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter` already exists. It says it's trying to overwrite it when installing.

Comment: Also try `sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk` instead

Comment: @Column01 Yes, `/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter` exists and if I run `sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk` I get exactly the same error.

Comment: That means Tkinter is installed already. Try importing it and using it but make sure the script uses the right env

Comment: @Column01 `/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/user/Development/tturtle.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'`

Comment: `import tkinter` try that. If that doesn't work, delete the tkinter folder and reinstall it using `sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this solution fits for every situation, but here is one that worked for me.

I had the same issue (except it was with Ubuntu 16.04), also tried what @Column01 wrote in comments:
`sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk`

Same problem.
But that gave me an idea. Checked:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.5.2
```

So the solution was as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-tk
```